# My flag was declined because I didn't use standard flagging options, but that option wasn't available

Tags: feature-request, android-app, user-experience

I flagged a question via the android app and wanted to choose the "primarly opinion" option. However, that option isn't immediately available via mobile and the fact that there are subsequent screens when choosing one of the available options isn't clear. Via the web you choose a radio button option and the page script brings you to the subsequent options page. I didn't see my option on mobile and choose to flag a moderator.

[image: rejected flag]

[image: screenshot with flagging options]

Comment: *It should be closed for another reason* lists the options.

Comment: So "should be closed for another reason" isn't available in the android app?

Comment: @psubsee2003: it is right there in the screenshot.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yup, i know that now after researching for posting this question, but that's not entirely clear.

Comment: 'for another reason...' even has ..., a [widely-recognized affordance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/17/133181.aspx) for 'another option follows'.

Comment: @Mar i see it, the comment was a bad attempt at humor

Answer (score 8):

You apparently missed the following option in the flagging menu:

[image: it should be closed for another reason...]

The per-site closing reasons, including 'primarily opinion based' are listed there.